My flutter application are not install on my device .Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly Error launching applica
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on V2111.
show this error how to slove it
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on V2111.

What? We can't even understand a thing.
